Adding JButton to Slick2D
Hy everyone ! I'm working on a project for my prep class and I must use Slick2D. I've created button with JButton, but now, I'm having a problem with how I must rendering them on Slick. Does someone have an idea ?
Thank you for your help !
So this is my init part of the Menu State:
public class MenuState extends BasicGameState {
    private Music music;
    private Sound button;
    private Image background;
    private JButton start;
    private JButton options;
    private JButton load;
    private JButton exit;
    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setSize(400, 600);
        start = new JButton ("src/MenuImages/Start.png");
        options = new JButton ("src/MenuImages/Options.png");
        load = new JButton ("src/MenuImages/Load.png");
        exit = new JButton ("src/MenuImages/Exit.png");
        frame.add(start);
        frame.add(options);
        frame.add(load);
        frame.add(exit);
        button = new Sound("src/Sound/interface.ogg");
        music = new Music("src/Sound/loop-menu.ogg");
        music.play();
        music.setVolume(1f);
        background = new Image("src/MenuImages/MainMenu.png");
        ((AppGameContainer) gc).setDisplayMode(400, 600, false);

    }

and this is my rendering part:
@Override
    public void render(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
        frame.repaint();
    }


